# Control audio on lock screen using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have background mode active for audio and I use this method to play files, but I can't control them when the screen is locked.

```
func loadSound(resource: String, soundExtension: String) {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resource, withExtension: soundExtension) else {
        return
    }

    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For someone with the same problem, call this method in the question method

```
fileprivate let remoteCommandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

func activateControlCenterCommands() {

    remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePlayCommandEvent(_:)))
    remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePauseCommandEvent(_:)))

    remoteCommandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
    remoteCommandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
}
```